# Meteor App: How to access the global window object

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to port some javascript code into Meteor.  It includes the following:

window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var audioContext = new AudioContext();

It also uses window. in other ways.

How is it possible to do this in Meteor?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried leaving it unchanged, putting it inside an `if (Meteor.isClient)`?

Comment: As far as I know Meteor doesn't erase properties of the window object - why would it?

Comment: why is this a question? this should work out of the box. Have you actually tried it? does anything not work?

Comment: It has to be in isClient block or in client/ directory - window object is reachable in those two cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Sindis above, it has to be in isClient block or in client/ directory - window object is reachable in those two cases.